# Center align thumbnails in a row - Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a following code -

```
<div class="row text-center" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/154x122/?text=Product">
                <div class="caption text-center">
                    <h4>Product Name</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/154x122/?text=Product">
                <div class="caption text-center">
                    <h4>Product Name</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/154x122/?text=Product">
                <div class="caption text-center">
                    <h4>Product Name</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/154x122/?text=Product">
                <div class="caption text-center">
                    <h4>Product Name</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot of current implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTluW.png)

I'm not able to get them centered in the `row` div. I tried many options found here on SO but not able to get working.

I may have varying number of thumbnails so I cannot add any pull or offset classes here.

How to get them centrally aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your first column div a extra class `col-md-offset-2` Like Below

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
```

---

If you cannot use `offset` then you should add class `center-divs` to all `col-` divs and add below code to yur custom css.

```
.center-divs{
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you, please see my additional info about varying number of thumbnails.

Comment: @Tunoz i have updated my answer for your additional requirement